# Convert Time received from server(which is UTC timing ) to Local timing

Tags: android, date, time

I'm receiving time from server which follows UTC time zone & follows 12 HR Format like this(7/30/2013 6:44:22 AM)

Can anyone pls. tell me how to get this particular timing converted to Local time & display it as (12:20 )(which must be in 24Hr format)

Here is the code I tried :

```
object._chatCreatedDateTime=obj.getString("CreatedDateTime");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
date  = format.format(Date.parse(object._chatCreatedDateTime));
object._chatCreatedDateTime=date;
```

Here (object._chatCreatedDateTime) is the time received from server & I converted it to particular format & push it back to local database which is not yielding proper result.

Answer (score 1):

To get the time in 24 hour patern use

> "H:mm"

as time pattern string.

> H represents hour in day(0-23)

So modify ur code as below,

```
object._chatCreatedDateTime=obj.getString("CreatedDateTime");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));date = format.format(Date.parse(object._chatCreatedDateTime));

object._chatCreatedDateTime=date;
```

Comment: I want time to be adjusted as per my location

Comment: Use `formatDateTime (Context context, long millis, int flags)` which returns date or time according to local convention. It has an argument named flag `flag` which when provided with a constant `FORMAT_24HOUR` return the time in 24 hour format.